# Fire function when returning to a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a javascript / jQuery method to fire a function when returning to a tab. I'm tracking the amount of time spent on an ad by using getDate on load, and subtracting the difference when leaving the ad. However, some links from the ad lead to a new tab, and the user may return to keep interacting with the ad. What can I used to restart the timer when a user navigates back to that tab? Onload won't seem to work since the tab is already loaded, and onfocus fires too many times (the user interacts with the ad to perform a live search of inventory). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(window).on('blur focus', function(e) {
  // The window has been focussed, when previously blurred.
  if(e.type == 'focus' && $(this).data('type') == 'blur') {
    alert('You have returned!')
  }
  // Store the event type.
  $(this).data('type', e.type)
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly on return to the tab. Thanks for the help!